# Uploading a file to http(s) server using POST request through libcurl in c

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

i want to upload a file to http server with post request, for this i am using libcurl.

```
static int copy_to_http_server(char *src, char *disp_src, char srcflag,
                                 char *dst, char *disp_dst, char dstflag)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  char *url = disp_dst;
  char *outfilename = src;

  struct curl_httppost *formpost=NULL;
  struct curl_httppost *lastptr=NULL;
  struct curl_slist *headerlist=NULL;
  static const char buf[] = "Expect:";

  /* src = /users/play/team.jpg 
   * url = http://10.1.2.3/repo/team_server.jpg 
   * i want 'src' to be copied under 'repo' directory on http server and 
   * the file name on the server should be team_server.jpg or team.jpg is
   * also fine */

  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

  /* Fill in the file upload field */
  curl_formadd(&formpost,
               &lastptr,
               CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "sendfile",
               CURLFORM_FILE, src,
               CURLFORM_END);

  /* Fill in the filename field */
  curl_formadd(&formpost,
               &lastptr,
               CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "filename",
               CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, src,
               CURLFORM_END);
  /* Fill in the submit field too, even if this is rarely needed */
  curl_formadd(&formpost,
             &lastptr,
             CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "submit",
             CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "send",
             CURLFORM_END);

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  /* initialize custom header list (stating that Expect: 100-continue is     not
     wanted */
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
    /* what URL that receives this POST */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    if (res != CURLE_OK) {
       printf("could not set url : %s\n",curl_easy_strerror(res));
    } else {
      printf("able to set\n");
    }  
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_HTTP | CURLPROTO_HTTPS);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, formpost);

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
        printf("calling curl_easy_perform\n");
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */
    if(res != CURLE_OK){
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));
    }
        printf("after calling curl_easy_perform\n");
    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    /* then cleanup the formpost chain */
    curl_formfree(formpost);
  }
  curl_global_cleanup();
  return 1;
}
```

below is the verbose output that i am getting as post response :-

```
> POST /repo/proc.out HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.1.2.3
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 0
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------8708d4558a12

< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Date: Sat, 28 May 2016 07:37:10 GMT
* Server Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
< Content-Length: 289
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /repo/proc.out was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at 10.1.2.3 Port 80</address>
</body></html>
* Closing connection 0
```

Most amazing part is i am not able to upload the file even with command line , and getting same error :-
  curl -F filedata=@myfile.txt http://10.1.2.3/repo

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /repo/ was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at 10.1.2.3 Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

but i am able to download a file from the same path i.e "http://10.1.2.3/repo/available_file.jpeg"

do i need anything extra to configure on http server or any script/programm should be running on the server to upload  a file to server ?

could any one please help ?

Comment: What is running on the server? Can you show the handler for the post request?

Comment: a 404 back means you're not even sending this to the correct URL...

Comment: @DanielStenberg i am able to access "http://10.1.2.3/repo/" on my web browser and it lists all the files and directory available . and suppose it contains "available_file.jpeg", then i am able to download it through curl request by passing the url as "http://10.1.2.3/repo/available_file.jpeg". 
Now i want to upload a file suppose "send_file.jpeg" to "http://10.1.2.3/repo/" with POST but it says "The requested URL /repo/ was not found on this server". how this can not be available in case of POST ?

Comment: @cnicutar sorry i didn't get "What is running on the server?". please look into the above code for POST related query.

Comment: did anyone got any clue ??

Answer (score 0):

You need a CGI script to process your data at /repo or /repo/proc.out

The CGI script should be written in a language supported by your web server environment.

The script will read the environment, and the data sent to the script, process it, and then send a response to your curl script.

Some web servers come with a default CGI script that will just dump the data back to you. It might be found in the cgi-bin directory.

Comment: you mean to say , i need to have a script running on the server ?

Comment: Yes, the script is executed by  your web server software using whatever scripting language that is defined in the header of that script.